# Permission Error Configuring Apache as Proxy to Weblogic

Tags: apache, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am running into a permission issue configuring weblogic plugin module into Apache. 
I am running the setup over centos7 with mod_wl_24.so to interface with weblogic version 12.2.1.

```
[root@localhost lib]# systemctl status httpd.service -l
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-07-22 05:04:00 EDT; 6min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2755 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2753 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2753 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 22 05:03:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain httpd[2753]: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 63 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf: >   Cannot load modules/lib/mod_wl_24.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/lib/mod_wl_24.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain kill[2755]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 22 05:04:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

the Summary error is Cannot load modules/lib/mod_wl_24.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/lib/mod_wl_24.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied.

```
[root@localhost lib]# pwd
/etc/httpd/modules/lib
[root@localhost lib]# ls -ltr
total 63108
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   552105 Oct  6  2016 mod_wl.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   553043 Oct  6  2016 mod_wl_24.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    85877 Oct  6  2016 libopmnsecure.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    67967 Oct  6  2016 libonssys.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10262948 Oct  6  2016 libnnz11.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   326469 Oct  6  2016 libdms2.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 52761218 Oct  6  2016 libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       12 Jul 21 14:09 libclntsh.so.11.1 -> libclntsh.so
```

Noted security Context was different :-

```
[root@localhost modules]#  ls -Z /etc/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_modules_t:s0 /etc/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
[root@localhost modules]# ls -Z /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0   /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so

chcon --type httpd_modules_t /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so

[root@localhost modules]# ls -Zd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_modules_t:s0 
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wl_24.so
```

The error has changed too 
     Cannot load modules/mod_wl_24.so into server: libopmnsecure.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please advise.

Comment: Notice output of ls -Z

Answer (score 0):

Found more dependecies. I could not find a way to ensure Apache refers /etc/httpd/modules/lib for the .so files. changing the security context and moving the files into modules worked.